# jQuery UI Autocomplete stops working after exactly 2041 records

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

My jQuery UI Autocomplete suddenly stopped working. Apparently my table size is too big, because when I limit the available records to 2040 or any number beneath that, it works perfectly, but breaks then I limit it to 2041 or any number above that.

Here's the full code that doesn't work:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
    $(function() {
      var availableTags = [
        <%= raw(Page.pluck(:name).map { |name| "\"#{name}\"" }.join(",\n")) %>
      ];
      function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
      }
      function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
      }

      $( "#pages" )
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
          if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
              $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        })
        .autocomplete({
          minLength: 0,
          source: function( request, response ) {
            // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
            response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
              availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
          },
          focus: function() {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
          },
          select: function( event, ui ) {
            var terms = split( this.value );
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            terms.push( ui.item.value );
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push( "" );
            this.value = terms.join( ", " );
            return false;
          }
        });
    });
    </script>
  </head>

  <div class="ui-widget">
    <textarea id="pages" name="pages" size="50"></textarea>
  </div><br>
```

And here's an example of code that does work:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
    $(function() {
      var availableTags = [
        <%= raw(Page.limit(2040).pluck(:name).map { |name| "\"#{name}\"" }.join(",\n")) %>
      ];
      function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
      }
      function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
      }

      $( "#pages" )
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
          if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
              $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        })
        .autocomplete({
          minLength: 0,
          source: function( request, response ) {
            // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
            response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
              availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
          },
          focus: function() {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
          },
          select: function( event, ui ) {
            var terms = split( this.value );
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            terms.push( ui.item.value );
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push( "" );
            this.value = terms.join( ", " );
            return false;
          }
        });
    });
    </script>
  </head>

  <div class="ui-widget">
    <textarea id="pages" name="pages" size="50"></textarea>
  </div><br>
```

Why does the table size matter? Can I change the limit somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, the limit here is not from the jquery, but from the string that you have interpolate:

```
Page.limit(2040).pluck(:name).map { |name| "\"#{name}\"" }.join(",\n")
```

IIRC, the max length of a string in ruby is 65535 characters, so let say the average length of name is about 30 characters, 2040 is the limit it could reach.

Solution: You could try a loop and interpolate each name instead to see if it works.